# How to obtain 64-bit binaries of Intel Fortran libraries for which I lack source code?

Tags: c++, fortran, static-libraries

I have the source code for an application which currently builds as 32-bit, and I want to rebuild it to target a 64-bit machine, using Visual Studio 2010 on Windows 7.

I have attempted to do this by going to `Project > Properties > configuration Properties > Configuration Manager > Active Solution Platform >` and selecting `x64`, and also `Copy settings from Win32`. Then I proceed to build the solution. The building process gives a lot of warnings (but this also happens with the 32-bit build, and I think has to do with the fact that the original application was built using VS2005). The build has a single error:

`lnk1112 module machine type x86 conflicts with target machine type x64`

From what I researched in the internet, this had to do with the 64-bit solution trying to use libraries compiled for a 32-bit machine. I verified this using dumpbin.exe -headers <*.lib file> for all the *.lib files in the source code.  All of them say "x86" on the header.

I am fairly confident that I can rebuild the libraries I have source code for, however there are a number of libraries (the dreaded Intel Fortran Libraries) that are also provided and used in the original solution, that were written for 32-bit:

> - IFCONSOL.lib
> - LIBIFCORE.lib
> - LIBIFCOREMT.lib
> - libirc.lib
> - libm.lib

Evidently, I do not have the source code for these libraries, and thus I would be unable to obtain "64-bit" versions. I have searched in the internet for "ifconsol.lib 64 bit" and the like, etc., but I have not found nothing meaningful.

My question is then, what are my options? If my solution needs these libraries, how can I obtain similar ones for 64-bit?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. You should avoid redundant and chatty text in posts, and try to stick solely to describing the problem, so as to make it more readable. I've edited your post to make it less verbose.

Comment: *how can I obtain similar ones for 64-bit?* Well, you could buy them from Intel. Not sure this warrants a Q&A here on SO.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/q/6810541/1227469

Comment: It is probably not duplicate of that one. Anyway the question should be asked on the official Intel Support Forum.

Comment: @VladimirF The question asks, "what are my options"? so it is at least a partial duplicate.

Comment: @JBentley Thank you for the editing.  However, you left out a crucial part of my post: that I have close to zero/nil experience building solutions and my knowledge of programming is very basic. I also apologized if my question seemed silly.  By eliminating that part, the answers I obtained perhaps are not as comprehensive as they could have been!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is little more than a "let me google that for you" answer.  Using the search term "intel fortran redistributable libraries" will give you lots of hits, the first of which is [Redistributable libraries for the Intel® C++ and Visual Fortran Compiler 11.1 for Windows](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/redistributable-libraries-of-the-intel-c-and-fortran-compiler-for-windows).  The libraries are for the 11.1 version of IVF and you may need a different version (it is unclear from your post).   These libraries can also be found in any licensed release of the intel compilers.

NOTE: for x64 download the "Intel 64" version of the packages.  The "IA-64" version is for Itanium processors, which will not work for you.

Comment: Hello @Casey, thank you for your comment. My post was edited for brevity and the part that said that I am a very novice programmer was left out. Only to clarify: is there such a thing as a 64-bit version of the fortran libraries I mention? I installed the redistributable libraries from the link you provided, but I can not find the files they contain.  Thanks for your help!

Comment: @user3756361 I don't have a windows machine to install the package from the site I linked to check what is included.  It is possible it will just be DLLs.  If the LIB files are not in there, you will need to download a version of the compiler from intel to obtain the linking libraries.  There are evaluation licenses, so you shouldn't have to spend any money for them.